# Method to resize CALayer frame on window resize?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-animation

I draw a series of images to various `CALayer` sublayers, then add those sublayers to a `superlayer`:

```
- (void)renderImagesFromArray:(NSArray *)array {
    CALayer *superLayer = [CALayer layer];
    for (id object in array) {
        CALayer* subLayer = [CALayer layer];
        // Disregard...
        NSURL *path = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:@[NSHomeDirectory(), @"Desktop", object]];
        NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:path];
        [self positionImage:image layer:subLayer];
        subLayer.contents = image;
        subLayer.hidden = YES;
        [superLayer addSublayer:subLayer];
    }
    [self.view setLayer:superLayer];
    [self.view setWantsLayer:YES];
    // Show top layer
    CALayer *top = superLayer.sublayers[0];
    top.hidden = NO;
}
```

I then call `[self positionImage: layer:]` to stretch the `CALayer` to it's maximum bounds ([essentially using the algorithm for the CSS `cover` property](http://blog.vjeux.com/2013/image/css-container-and-cover.html)), and position it in the center of the window:

```
- (void)positionImage:(NSImage *)image layer:(CALayer *)layer{
    float imageWidth = image.size.width;
    float imageHeight = image.size.height;
    float frameWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    float frameHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    float aspectRatioFrame = frameWidth/frameHeight;
    float aspectRatioImage = imageWidth/imageHeight;
    float computedImageWidth;
    float computedImageHeight;
    float verticalSpace;
    float horizontalSpace;
    if (aspectRatioImage <= aspectRatioFrame){
        computedImageWidth = frameHeight * aspectRatioImage;
        computedImageHeight = frameHeight;
        verticalSpace = 0;
        horizontalSpace = (frameWidth - computedImageWidth)/2;
    } else {
        computedImageWidth = frameWidth;
        computedImageHeight = frameWidth / aspectRatioImage;
        horizontalSpace = 0;
        verticalSpace = (frameHeight - computedImageHeight)/2;
    }
    [CATransaction flush];
    [CATransaction begin];
    CATransaction.disableActions = YES;
    layer.frame = CGRectMake(horizontalSpace, verticalSpace, computedImageWidth, computedImageHeight);
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

This all works fine, except when the window gets resized. I solved this (in a very ugly way) by subclassing `NSView`, then implementing the only method that was actually called when the window resized, `viewWillDraw:`:

```
- (void)viewWillDraw{
    [super viewWillDraw];
    [self redraw];
}

- (void)redraw{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[NSApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CALayer *superLayer = self.layer;
    NSArray *sublayers = superLayer.sublayers;
    NSImage *image;
    CALayer *current;
    for (CALayer *view in sublayers){
        if (!view.isHidden){
            current = view;
            image = view.contents;
        }
    }
    [appDelegate positionImage:image layer:current];
}
```

So... what's the right way to do this? `viewWillDraw:` get's called too many times which means I have to do unnecessary and redundant calculations, and I can't use `viewWillStartLiveResize:` because I need to constantly keep the image in its correct position. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Have you tried setting the layers' `autoresizingMask`s (including the parent layer's)? What did you set them to? Alternatively, have you considered using CALayer's layout API?

Comment: @PeterHosey I originally set each child layer to `NSViewHeightSizable | NSViewWidthSizable`, but that wouldn't work because I need to retain the aspect ratio.

Comment: @PeterHosey Is it acceptable to use `setLayerContentsRedrawPolicy:NSViewLayerContentsRedrawDuringViewResize` and then implement `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`?

Comment: You aren't supposed to override `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`. Have you looked at CALayer's layout API yet?

Comment: @PeterHosey Why is that? And I'm not sure what you're referring to when you say layout API, do you mean `setNeedsLayout`? Or am I overlooking a section in the NSView docs...

Comment: @PeterHosey Actually, figured it out, I think...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Peter Hosey was right; my original method was clunky, and I shouldn't have been overriding `setNeedsDisplayInRect:`. I first made sure that I was using an auto layout in my app, then implemented the following:

```
subLayer.layoutManager  = [CAConstraintLayoutManager layoutManager];
subLayer.autoresizingMask = kCALayerHeightSizable | kCALayerWidthSizable;
subLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
```

Basically, I set the sublayer's `autoResizingMask` to stretch both horizontally and vertically, and then set `contentsGravity` to preserve the aspect ratio.

That last variable I found by chance, but it's worth noting that you can [only use a few `contentsGravity` constants if](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), like in my case, you're setting an `NSImage` as the layer's `contents`:

> That method creates an image that is suited for use as the contents of a layer and that is supports all of the layer’s gravity modes. By contrast, the NSImage class supports only the kCAGravityResize, kCAGravityResizeAspect, and kCAGravityResizeAspectFill modes.

Always fun when a complicated solution can be simplified to 3 lines of code.

Comment: CAConstraintLayoutManager is separate from (and older than) Auto Layout for views.

Comment: @PeterHosey Thanks for the clarification. Thinking they were related pushed me into updating my xib file with Auto Layout, however, which further simplified my code.